# Uploading video caption as non-owner returns 403

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use python to upload caption to one of my Youtube video with a different account. I'm always getting 403. Using my own account works, though.

I already have Youtube Data API v3 enabled in my project, with an OAuth 2.0 client of type "Other" set up. Then I downloaded the Python caption management sample code and modified it to use my own client secrets:

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/captions.py

I've also downloaded youtube-v3-api-captions.json. All required libraries are also already installed.

Then I ran ./captions.py --videoid='MY_VIDEO' --file='MY_CAPTION' --language='en' --action=='upload', logged in with my second account in browser, and got 403:

"The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to upload the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized."

So, do I need extra permissions to upload captions as non-owner? Or is the API for owner only?

Comment: 403 errors are explicitly permission denied errors. In this case: YouTube is checking to see if you are actually the owner of the video before allowing you to edit (which is its intended functionality). It wouldn’t make sense to have permissions to edit a video which isn’t yours

Comment: I'm not trying to edit the video, but only to add a fan-contributed subtitle. The video has already allowed so, and I can do that manually with my second account. So I think it should make sense if doing that with API is allowed?

Comment: So you have Auth credentials for both accounts?

Comment: I do. For the tests I did, both accounts are mine.